# How to catch mousemove over HTCAPTION

Tags: c#, mousemove

I have a form that sets all its background as HTCAPTION as the source code below.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch(m.Msg)
        {
            case Global.WM_NCHITTEST:
                Point mouseCursor = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

                if (mouseCursor.X < borderSize && mouseCursor.Y < borderSize)
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)Global.HTTOPLEFT;
                else if (mouseCursor.X < borderSize && mouseCursor.Y > Height - borderSize)
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)Global.HTBOTTOMLEFT;
                else if (mouseCursor.X < borderSize)
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)Global.HTLEFT;
                else if (mouseCursor.X > Width - borderSize && mouseCursor.Y < borderSize)
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)Global.HTTOPRIGHT;
                else if (mouseCursor.X > Width - borderSize && mouseCursor.Y > Height - borderSize)
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)Global.HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
                else if (mouseCursor.X > Width - borderSize)
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)Global.HTRIGHT;
                else if (mouseCursor.Y < borderSize)
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)Global.HTTOP;
                else if (mouseCursor.Y > Height - borderSize)
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)Global.HTBOTTOM;
                else
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)Global.HTCAPTION;
                break;
        }
    }
```

The problme is that when the HTCAPTION is set, I can not trigger From.MouseMove event.

```
    private void FormMain_MouseMove(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = e.Location;

        Console.WriteLine(p);
    }
```

How can I catch the MouseMove event?

Answer (score 0):

In VB.net it's

```
MyBase.WndProc(m)
```

So, correct me if I'm wrong but in C# I'd guess.

```
this.WndProc(m)
```

?
Put that before your if statement.